# Adding two different buttons on each cells dynamically

Tags: javascript

Please I am building a dynamic table and I want when j==3; two different buttons(add and reject buttons) should be added. I don't know the best way it will appear in JSON format. And when I looped, I got only one button on the table. Is there a possible way to do this better? I am new to javaScript.
**This is js **

var contributionTable = document.querySelector("#contributionTable");

```
if(myContribution.contributions.length>0){
     var col = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < myContribution.contributions.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myContribution.contributions[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    } 
    // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
    var tHead = document.querySelector("#tableHead");    
    var hRow = document.querySelector("#tableRow");
    tHead.appendChild(hRow);
    contributionTable.appendChild(tHead);
    var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");    
    for (var i = 0; i < myContribution.contributions.length; i++) {

            var bRow = document.createElement("tr");
            var td = document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML = i+1;
                    bRow.appendChild(td);
         for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement("td");
               if (j==3) {
                for (let i = 0; i < myContribution.contributions.length; i++) {
                  let modify = myContribution.contributions[i].modify;

                    for(let j = 0; j < modify.length; j++){

                        if (td.textContent==="Accept") {
                          td.innerHTML='<div class="badge badge-success">'+modify[j]+'</div>';
                           bRow.appendChild(td);
                        }else
                            td.innerHTML='<div class="badge badge-danger">'+modify[j]+'</div>';
                             bRow.appendChild(td);
                  }
                    }
                  }else{
                      td.innerHTML = myContribution.contributions[i][col[j]];
                      bRow.appendChild(td);
                  }
          }

            tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
        }
    contributionTable.appendChild(tBody);
```

}

with the above, I got only the reject button but I want both the add and reject buttons to appear on the same cell in each row.

**This is my JSON data**

```
var myContribution =  {"contributions":
[
{
  "txnNo":"00031",
"name": "Onyinye Okeke",
"Delete":"Delete",
"modify":["Accept","Reject"],
"date":"2020-01-19",
"amount":"100000",
"desc": "Weekly"
},
{
  "txnNo":"00031",
"name": "Thompson Philip",
"Delete":"Delete",
"modify":["Accept","Reject"],
"date":"2019-11-09",
"amount":"70000",
"desc": "Daily"
}]}
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is your goal of your code. There's some missing logic part, such as your loop logic (what is "i", what is "j"). Moreover, you're reassigning "j" for a reason I don't know

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Your code is not clear, please add more code and try to explain your problem again.

Comment: I have edited my post. I am sorry if my first post was not well explained. i was trying to make the code easy and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
               var cellContent = '';
               for(let j = 0; j < modify.length; j++) {

                    if (td.textContent==="Accept")
                      cellContent +='<div class="badge badge-success">'+modify[j]+'</div>';
                    else 
                      cellContent +='<div class="badge badge-danger">'+modify[j]+'</div>';

              }
              td.innerHTML = cellContent;
              bRow.appendChild(td);
```

If you want to add styles to the buttons, it is better to update button style using CSS

```
 td > div.badge {
    margin: 0 5px; /* no space on top, 5px right space, no bottom space, 5px left space
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But please how do i give space between the two badges. let them be separated by a little space@ymz